# Nested Array of Structs inside another Struct

Tags: c, arrays, struct, nested

I am trying to model a cache simulator, I didn't post all my code because I have all of the logic set up already, but I am trying to use structs to accomplish the task at hand.

I have two types of structs, one for Lines, which contain:

int LineIndex
unsigned Long tagbits
int vbit

I then have a struct set which contains:

int LRU
int SetIndex
Line* SetLines

Now I am picturing this like a two dimensional array. I make a variable Cache which is a pointer to a Set. The code is below.....

```
typedef struct{
    int Vbit;
    unsigned long LineTagBits;
    int LineIndex;
}Line;

typedef struct{
    Line* SetLines;
    int LRU;
    int SetIndex;
}Set;

int s, b, E, SetNum, BlockNum, i, c = 0;
unsigned long SetMask, BlockMask,TagMaks = 0;
Set* Cache = NULL;
Line* SetLines = NULL;


void MallocAndInitialize(){
    Set Cache[SetNum];
    for (int i = 0; i < SetNum; i++){
        Cache[i].LRU = 0;//set LRU line
        Cache[i].SetIndex = i;//set set INDEX
        printf("You are at Set %i \n", Cache[i].SetIndex);
        Cache[i].SetLines = (Line *)malloc(E * sizeof(Line));
        for (int j = 0; j < E; j++){
            Cache[i].SetLines[j].Vbit = 0;
            Cache[i].SetLines[j].LineIndex = j;
            Cache[i].SetLines[j].LineTagBits = 0;
            printf("Set %i, Line %i\n", Cache[i].SetIndex, Cache[i].SetLines[j].LineIndex);
            }
        }
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){


    while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, "s:E:b:")) != -1)
{
        switch (c){
        case's':
          s = atoi(optarg);
          SetNum = 1 << s;
          MallocAndInitialize();
          break;
        case'E':
          E = atoi (optarg);
          break;
        case 'b':
          b = atoi (optarg);
          BlockNum = 1 << b;
          break;
        default:
          printf("Error!");
          exit(1);
        }
    }

    //printSummary(0, 0, 0);
    free(Cache);
    return 0;
}
```

Now the Problem is it will do the first print statement in MallocandInitialize, but it will not do the second print statement. I am trying to figure out if I am not accessing each line correctly. Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: When the problem occurs, if you print out the value of `E` before entering the second `for` loop do you see that `E` > 0?

Comment: I just added a print statement after the Set Index print statement to grab the show the value of E, it is 0, but it shouldn't be....suggestions?

Comment: Is E initialized before you call MallocAndInitialize? Be careful with the order of your command line arguments. Be sure E has a value before you call MallocAndInitialize.

Comment: Yeah I just realized it...I feel like an idiot because I've been trying to figure it out for a couple hours now. Thanks both for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any assurance that when *MallocandInitialize* is called, E is assigned a particular value.

Are you sure that E is greater than zero?

please try to print it before going into the inside loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your program is dependent on the order of the command line arguments.

-E is needed to set the global variable 'E'. But -s will call MallocAndInitialize
which reads E.

This is not a good organization of your code.

I'd suggest moving `MallocAndInitialize` out of the loop that processes the arguments.

Comment: One step ahead of you..thanks for the input! I was debugging this for hours like a dummy.